# Discord.py Bot renaming a VoiceChannel only works sometimes

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot written in discord.py and wanna rename a voice channel. It sometimes works but sometimes it doesn't. And I get no error.

Here's the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "s!close" in message.content:
        voice_channel = client.get_channel(711953093335449632)
        await voice_channel.edit(name="support-closed")
```

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible code.

Comment: We need the entire event function or command which contains this code please.

Comment: @CaptainSword I've just tried out the code for myself, and it seems to work fine. Would you be able to supply me with some conditions/instructions on how to reproduce the bug?

Comment: when i do it several times it will stop. Maybe try it ten times in a row

Comment: @CaptainSword is there another command you use to rename the channel? Or do you change it manually

Comment: there is also an open command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Channels have recently been rate-limited in discord to prevent spamming the API and degrading server performance.

[image]