# Discord won't edit voice_channel name after changed once or twice

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to add a feature to my DiscordBot, showing the member-count in form of a voice_channel name.
The member-count should also update, if somebody joins or leaves the server.

Here is the code:

```
async def memberUpdate(guild):
    categories = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Stats")
    voice = discord.utils.get(categories.voice_channels, name=str(categories.voice_channels[0])) # Get the first voice_channel in this category

    update = "Member count: " + str(guild.member_count) 
    await voice.edit(name=update) # Edit voice channel

# First Time setting it up with "stats"-command
@bot.command()
async def stats(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild

    # Write message, if this category already exists!
    if discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.name == "Stats", guild.categories):
        await ctx.message.channel.send("The category already exists!")

    # If not, do this:
    elif discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.name == "Stats", guild.categories) is None:
        await guild.create_category("Stats")
        category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Stats")

        await category.create_voice_channel("Member count: ")

        await memberUpdate(guild) # Update it for the first time when set up

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = member.guild

    await memberUpdate(guild)

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    guild = member.guild

    await memberUpdate(guild)
```

For understanding reasons, I only translated names and comments.

When I set it up for the first time, the memberUpdate works finely, updating the member count.
When I let somebody join the server, it also activated the update-function. But when I remove the same person, it doesn't change it at all.
I tried to figure out whether the on_member_remove event does troubles, but when I set it u again and remove somebody **first**, the member count updates. After that it just won't edit anyting anymore.

Is that a probelm with Discord, not being able to change channel_names that quickly? Or is it a problem in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to Diggy's answer here: [Discord.py Bot renaming a VoiceChannel only works sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62470067/discord-py-bot-renaming-a-voicechannel-only-works-sometimes)

The API was updated to only allow 2 updates to a channel's properties every 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks so much !
I spent 2 days trying all kind of stuff, thinking I messed up with asynchronous calls.
In the end my function calls were just delayed by discord...